# Linux read system call logged by strace - how to understand pointer to buffer value?

Tags: c, pointers, file-descriptor, strace

I ran `strace` and in its output I got lines like:

```
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\273\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
```

I've read man on [read](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), so string `""` is pointer to buf (`ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);`), but what does that particular string mean? In particular:

- `ELF` most probably executable-linked - why here for pointer?
- `\` lets escape special characters - why escape digits here?
- `>` what is it for?

Comment: That's data from the read. The escaped values are in octal.

Comment: @Hasturkun, I've found in `man strace` "character pointers are dereferenced to C strings", that is all I could now find searching for `read`. Could you please post a link/pointer where I can read more on that?

Comment: What format is the file you're reading? Look it up and see what all those bytes mean.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#File_header

Comment: @Shawn, thank you. I now see it's contents of the file, file is library one. One remaining is why strace gives octal numbers? particular wish of developers?

Comment: Base 8 is the default for printing non-ascii bytes in many utilities. There's probably an option to use base 16 instead.

Comment: @Hasturkun, , do you want to write an answer for me to upvote and accept? or such simple question better be deleted maybe?

Comment: @ Shawn, same about answer to you too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're seeing here is the dynamic loader opening and reading the header of the needed libraries. Almost any `strace` of an ELF program (which is the standard executable format in Linux) starts with a bunch of `open`/`read`/`mmap`/`close` for this reason: the dynamic loader is loading the needed libraries.

What you see here:

```
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\273\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
```

Is just what the loader is reading from the file:

- `3`: this is the `fd` that was assigned to the open file by `open()`.
- `"\177ELF\2\1\1\0..."`: this is is the content of the file that is being read. Numbers are there because those are octal escape sequences, for example `\1` means the byte 1. They are printed like this because otherwise you would not be able to see them, and would create a mess on your terminal, since most of those are special non printable characters.
- `832`: this is the number of bytes the loader wants to read from the file.
- `= 832`: this is the result of the `read()`, which means that all the requested bytes were read.

In other words, **those escape sequences, are just a way to make non-printable bytes human readable**. You can test this running `od -bc` on the file that the loader is trying to open, you can see its content in octal form plus with printable characters and backslash escapes:

```
$ od -bc /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | head -n4
0000000 177 105 114 106 002 001 001 003 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
        177   E   L   F 002 001 001 003  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000020 003 000 076 000 001 000 000 000 260 034 002 000 000 000 000 000
        003  \0   >  \0 001  \0  \0  \0 260 034 002  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
```

---

A more complete example would be the following, from `strace /bin/true`:

```
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
read(4, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\4\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1689360, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0d3d877000
mmap(NULL, 3795296, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0) = 0x7f0d3d2dd000
mprotect(0x7f0d3d472000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f0d3d672000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x195000) = 0x7f0d3d672000
mmap(0x7f0d3d678000, 14688, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0d3d678000
close(4)
```

You can see that the loader is opening "libc", which is the ELF file for the standard C library. It reads its header to determine which sections are to be loaded, and then `mmap`s all the needed sections in memory, assigning the right permissions.

Comment: thank you. one related question I have reading `strace` output: why all these 0x7f0d3d672000 are different? why not next line uses output of previous one? I guess the app does some calculations in between, but maybe other reason.

Comment: @Marisha yes, that's exactly the reason. The dynamic loader does the needed calculations to determine exactly where the sections need to be loaded in memory. Those numbers may seem randomic because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) being enabled on your system.